# How to Control first port of USRP N210 to use it when i need using matlab coding?

Tags: matlab, port, signal-processing, usrp, tx

I’m working on a radar project using USRP N210 with UBX-40 daughterboard using matlab. I need a code to control the first port of the usrp, because the first port can be used as tx/rx. Such as in tx part, I can turn ON transmitting and OFF Receiving & vice versa. So I can transmit and receive from same antenna. Any Help!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used matlab to interface with the USRP but I assume it uses the C API.
Here you can see all the parameters to configure the USRP. https://kb.ettus.com/Getting_Started_with_UHD_and_C%2B%2B

When you pass "TX/RX" to the antenna parameter it will automatically select the port TX/RX port for you. It is not recommended to use the same antenna, rather use the RX antenna to receive and TX/RX antenna to transmit. If you are not required to receive the signal you transmit, then you can switch between TX and RX on the same antenna with some sort of control but I still wouldn't recommend doing that :)